# strg+click doesn't work with sts for variables

Tags: spring-tool-suite

This is a issue which bother me a long time.

Now i found the solution so i wanted to share it.

When i open a class in the editor i got the problem that the navigation to the declaration of a class, method is working, but when i want to navigate to a the declaration of an variable it doesn't work.

I also discovered that this problem is happening with sts 3.6.4.RELEASE and also with 3.7.0.RELEASE.

After some investigation i found this stacktrace in my sts logs.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:148)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:117)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinksHelper(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:94)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.quickfix.hyperlinks.AutowireHyperlinkDetector.addHyperlinks(AutowireHyperlinkDetector.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.detectHyperlinks(JavaElementHyperlinkDetector.java:114)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.HyperlinkDetectorRegistry$HyperlinkDetectorDelegate.detectHyperlinks(HyperlinkDetectorRegistry.java:80)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:289)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.findHyperlinks(HyperlinkManager.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.HyperlinkManager.mouseMove(HyperlinkManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:212)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: I created a JIRA ticket for this: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4171. Would be great if you could attach a sample project that helps us to reproduce this issue. That would be really great. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have some problems to reproduce this bug. At my Eclipse project this issue still exists if i not uncheck the option in my solution, but if i create a new project everything works fine. I have to make some investigation to find the reason and will post it then.

Comment: Ok, sure. Thanks for taking a look and for trying to create a reproducible sample project. Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to go to

General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking

and to deactivate "Autowire Hyperlink Detector".